# Event to update a column won't run

Tags: mysql, update, mysql-event

I have successfully created an event in MySQL to update a column called `dob` in a table called `auth`.

My problem is that the event won't run. Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$
   CREATE EVENT update_event1
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
   ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
  DO
    BEGIN
      UPDATE auth set dob=DATE_ADD(dob,INTERVAL 1 DAY) ;
    END $$;
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: check to see if event scheduler is running..use  show variables like 'event_scheduler'; to see..Moreover you can see error log to see if there is any error encountered in the event.. Have used the same code and it is working on my side..it seem event scheduler is off in your environment

Comment: @NawazSohail your comment should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

It seem that your event scheduler is not running causing the problem of event not getting executed. use following command to check

```
show global variables like 'event_scheduler';
```

if you get that it is off, you can do if you are in MySQL 5.6 or higher

```
 set global event_scheduler=1;
```

or add the following line in cnf file to make this change permanent and in versions <5.6

```
 event_scheduler=ON
```

The given code would work once you turn on the event scheduler using above approach.

Hope it helps.